# How to remove value from FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-data

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax/5976031#5976031) is a way to `append` file to `FormData` :

```
  var data = new FormData();
  jQuery.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
          data.append('file-'+i, file);
  });
```

is it possible to do as below ?

```
     data[i].remove();???
 or  data[i] = file;??
```

how iIcan remove or modify a value from `data`

Comment: Check the value of `data` in firebug or the Chrome console, if you can.

Comment: It appears to me that no remove method is available. The idea with FormData is that it is meant to make a simple AJAX wrapper for a form element and allow you to append extra data before sending the request. If you want to remove items, I suggest working with a library like jQuery or making your own AJAX wrapper that expects a standard object so that you can add and remove items at will. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery delete value from FormData object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785906/jquery-delete-value-from-formdata-object)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot do anything other than append items to a FormData object. See [the Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#interface-formdata). It would be better if you use a dictionary/object to store all the values you want to add/modify before you actually construct the object.

```
var data = {};
jQuery.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
  data['file-'+i] = file;
});

//modify the object however you want to here

var formData = new FormData();
for (var key in data) {
  formData.append(key, data[key]);
}
```

Comment: The specification is actually there (at the same link), but not implemented by anyone. May be worth checking in the future to see.

Comment: @Marcel That would only be required if the server you're posting to requires it, in your case, PHP.

Comment: Seven years later, this isn't true anymore, [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) has a [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete) method now. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40561052/157247) elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 25):

I know this thread is old but I just found this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete

I'm sur it could help. You can use `formData.delete(name)` to delete the entry of formData with "name" key.

Comment: This doesn't work on 2 mobile browsers I tested on iOS 10 and Android 5.1

Comment: Check for browser compatibility here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Pretty acceptable compatibility now. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is the answer. Only not compatible with internet explorer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar problem, where I was submitting files to server and needed to remove files if user deletes from UI button next to each file.

So to do it, I reset the formData and created new formData like follows:

```
function removeFile(file_name, file_name_slug) {
        const files = [...formData.entries()];
        // reset formData
        formData.delete('files[]')
        files.forEach(function (item, index) {
            // if found
            if (item[1].name === file_name) {
                // remove from UI
                $(`#${file_name_slug}`).remove();
            }else{
                // make new formData without this item
                formData.append('files[]', item[1])
            }
        });
    }
```