# Jquery delete value from FormData object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, form-data

how I can delete value from FormData object with same name?
I have HTML form with two input files.

```
<input id="human" type="file" name="file[]" class="docfiles" />
<input id="animal" type="file" name="file[]" class="docfiles" />
```

For example I want to delete file 1 - with id "human". Any idea how to do this?

Here my demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmtsk812/1/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Manipulate the array of files and re-add the elements minus the one needed to be removed.

```
var files = formData.getAll("file[]");
files.splice($("[type='file']").index($("#animal")), 1);
formData.delete("file[]");
$.each(files, function(i, v) {
    formData.append("file[]", v);
});
```

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/nnte528L/

Comment: I was strugling almost one day. At the end you gave me a light. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the entire file list by setting the value property of the input object to an empty string.

```
document.getElementById('human').value = "";
```

If you are using FormData, you can also have

```
ForEach(var key in formData.keys()){
  formData.delete(key);
}
```

This will iterate through all keys in formData and delete all the key value pairs.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using jQuery you can use

```
$("#human").remove();
```

if you're using vanilla JS you can do the following

```
var human = document.getElementById('human');
human.parentNode.removeChild(human);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is not that i want. I try this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete) but "file" is array.