# getting appended formData file index based on filename

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, delete-file, form-data

So i've been learning about formData and now im trying to remove a file from it. Based on what i've read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), i can append a file like this:

```
formData.append('userpic', myFileInput.files[0], 'chris.jpg');
```

To remove a file, im trying to use the splice method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785906/jquery-delete-value-from-formdata-object/41786160), but i only use one input field to retrieve multiple (retrieve single file, append it, and retrieve another,not simultaneously multiple) files from user. But to be able to splice i need the proper index of the exact appended file i wish to remove, how can i get it? Is there any way to find the index of the file based on the filename such as 'chris.jpg' above?